# calculating mean using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have temp data like this:

```
date        tmax tmin dtr
2/13/2014   0   19  8
2/15/2014   2.8 15  10
1/29/2015   10  7   3
1/6/2016    3   4   -1
1/29/2016   2   2   0
5/5/2016    9   11  -2
5/7/2016    11  14  -3
1/29/2017   11  8   3
```

i need to be able to select all the rows with DTR less than or equal to zero and perform the following.

1. for those rows whose DTR is equal to zero, i want to replace tmax and tmin by following calculation:
   for example 1/29/2016, tmax = (10+11)/2 ie calculating the mean for 2016 from 2015 and 2017 and similar way for tmin.
2. for those rows with DTR less than zero, i want to replace both tmax and tmin with -99.9

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far, and point out exactly on which line of your code you are stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you're after.

```
import pandas as pd

# reading the data
df = pd.read_csv('input_data.csv',
                 delim_whitespace=True,
                 index_col=0,
                 parse_dates=True,
                 dtype={'tmax': 'float',
                        'tmin': 'float',
                        'dtr': 'int'})

# setting tmax and tmin to -99.9 if dtr < 0
df.ix[df['dtr']<0, ['tmax', 'tmin']] = -99.9

# iterate over the rows
for row in df.itertuples():

# if the dtr is 0
if row.dtr == 0:

    # set date, d to the current row
    d = row.Index

    # get dates of desired rows before and after d
    before = pd.Timestamp(d.year-1, d.month, d.day)
    after = pd.Timestamp(d.year+1, d.month, d.day)

    # set tmax and tmin to average of the above dates' data
    df.ix[d, 'tmax'] = (df.ix[before].tmax + df.ix[after].tmax) / 2
    df.ix[d, 'tmin'] = (df.ix[before].tmin + df.ix[after].tmin) / 2
```

The resulting dataframe is:

```
            tmax  tmin  dtr
date                       
2014-02-13   0.0  19.0    8
2014-02-15   2.8  15.0   10
2015-01-29  10.0   7.0    3
2016-01-06 -99.9 -99.9   -1
2016-01-29  10.5   2.0    0
2016-05-05 -99.9 -99.9   -2
2016-05-07 -99.9 -99.9   -3
2017-01-29  11.0   8.0    3
```

Comment: i ran the script and i get some error msg,   File "C:\Users\Xxxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\base.py", line 2134, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the full error. It will look something like `SomeError: Full error message`. It's hard to help otherwise.

Comment: thank you! i fixed it and now its working. what if i have to dtr for 2014 and 2017 is 0, as it does not have the reference series.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what you mean a bit more? What reference series? Also, if my answer has answered your original question could you please mark it as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
>>> df
        date  tmax  tmin   dtr
0  2/13/2014   0.0  19.0   8.0
1  2/15/2014   2.8  15.0  10.0
2  1/29/2015  10.0   7.0   3.0
3   1/6/2016   3.0   4.0  -1.0
4  1/29/2016   2.0   2.0   0.0
5   5/5/2016   9.0  11.0  -2.0
6   5/7/2016  11.0  14.0  -3.0
7  1/29/2017  11.0   8.0   3.0


>>> df.ix[df['dtr']<0, ['tmax', 'tmin']] = -99.9
>>> df.ix[df['dtr']==0, ['tmax', 'tmin']] = (10+11)/2
>>> df
        date  tmax  tmin   dtr
0  2/13/2014   0.0  19.0   8.0
1  2/15/2014   2.8  15.0  10.0
2  1/29/2015  10.0   7.0   3.0
3   1/6/2016 -99.9 -99.9  -1.0
4  1/29/2016  10.0  10.0   0.0
5   5/5/2016 -99.9 -99.9  -2.0
6   5/7/2016 -99.9 -99.9  -3.0
7  1/29/2017  11.0   8.0   3.0
```

Comment: for dtr < 0 is fine but for dtr==0, i need to get that 10 and 11 based on date and then take mean

Comment: can you elaborate with example i am not able to get what you up to.